# Most efficient way to save way points and do comparisons?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, nosql

I would like to know your opinion. I created an application, where users create routes and we track this route and save all the way points in the database. Then, the application does comparisons of users way points.

Currently, I use a `MSSQL` Server, using two tables, one for Routes and the other for storing way points (with spatial data type). The comparisons are made in a stored procedure using SQL Server geographic functions such as st_distance...

I have investigated other options. One that I implemented is with Oracle 11g using objects. I store all data in only one Object Table, and the way points are stored in a Varray of a type with Latitude and Longitude attributes. This way is very efficient saving and retrieving data, but gets some complicated when comparing.

I'm looking for a `NoSQL` solution, some algorithm or method to do this efficiently. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, it helped, thanks! I think the solution is not in the way I store the information, but in the algorithm to compare waypoints. To do this I first have to reduce the number of waypoints to the most relevant and uniform ones that can match with other routes and then do a comparison (as your answer states). I haven't really tested it, if it results with better performance I will post my solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using database functions like [STDistance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933808.aspx) for all n records is suboptimal. Your CPU overhead will increase exponentially.

What you should do is check for the amount of points within a rectangle around the current epicenter you are searching. Here's an example (in MySQL):

```
SELECT * FROM `points`
    WHERE `latitude` >= X1 AND `latitude` <= X2
    AND `longitude` >= Y1 AND `longitude` <= Y2
```

This provides a reduced `superset` of points that should then be further reduced by calculating the orthodromic distance (with respect to the curvature of the Earth) using the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

**Don't forget** to set up a [composite index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on `latitude` and `longitude`.

[image: Orthodromic distance]

Here it is in PHP:

```
<?php
function haversine($latitude1, $longitude1,
                   $latitude2, $longitude2, $unit = 'Mi') {
    $theta = $longitude1 - $longitude2;
    $distance = (sin(deg2rad($latitude1)) * sin(deg2rad($latitude2))) +
    (cos(deg2rad($latitude1)) * cos(deg2rad($latitude2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta)));
    $distance = acos($distance);
    $distance = rad2deg($distance);
    $distance = $distance * 60 * 1.1515;
    switch ($unit) {
    case 'Mi':
        break;
    case 'Km':
        $distance = $distance * 1.609344;
    }
    return (round($distance, 2));
}
?>
```

**To recap**:

Here's an example image illustrating what to do:

[image: Example with CN Tower]

The first search would involve a bounding box collision search (MySQL example) to determine the `superset`, excluding the red points. The second verification process would involve calculating if the points are within an appropriate orthodromic distance with the Haversine formula (PHP example) and taking a `subset` (composed of the black points).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'm going to think about a solution implementing this idea! I have a concern with this solution, i think it works fine for points that are very close, when we are talking about bigger distance, the points are spread in a bigger area, it gets complicated because it doesn't work for me to do a very big rectangle, the match criteria between routes must be more precise. Thank you!